# Run npm package as gulp task

Tags: gulp

I'd like to run this [sort-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sort-sass) package using a gulp task. It only gives instructions on running it through the cli or through node and I'm wondering if anyone can give me some tips on how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `sort-sass` doesn't accept file streams as input but it wants a string or buffer.

Here's the same example as in the `npm module` page:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sortSass = require('sort-sass');

gulp.task('sort-sass', [ /* list task deps here*/ ], function(){
    var sassString = fs.readFileSync('some.sass');
    var sortedSassString = sortSass(sassString);
    // do something here (perhaps write it)
    fs.writeFileSync('output.sass');
});
```

Here's the same task in his the async version (the same pattern works for all other `npm async modules`):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sortSass = require('sort-sass');

gulp.task('sort-sass', [ /* list task deps here*/ ], function(done){
  // read the file
  fs.readFile('some.sass', function(err, sassString){
    if(err){
      return done(err);
    }
    var sortedSassString = sortSass(sassString);

    // do somthing else with the string...
    // if you want to write it somewhere
    fs.writeFile( 'filename.sass', sortedSassString, function(done);

  });
});
```

Another solution could be to wrap such module with [a gulp plugin that deals with buffers](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/using-buffers.md) so that you can write something like this:

```
 var sortSass = require('sort-sass');

 gulp.task('sort-sass', [/* task deps here */], function(){
  return gulp.src('some.sass')
             .pipe(sortSass())
             .pipe(gulp.dest('output.sass');
 });
```